# Multiple versions of REST web service - Implementation error

Tags: web-services, rest, interface, jersey, ejb-3.0

I am trying to create a v2 of a web service. For this I created a new package com.package.v2 where the remote interface has been declared. If I keep the class name of v2 same as v1, then I get an error during the deployment to glassfish server.

```
SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: The class com.package.v2.TestRESTServiceBA is an interface and cannot be instantiated.|#]
```

If I rename the v2 class to a different name then everything works fine. Can you please let me know how I can keep both the version with the same name?

More details: 
        INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Root resource classes found:

interface com.package.v2.TestRESTServiceBA

interface com.package.v1.TestRESTServiceBA

Adding Code:

Version 1 Interface

```
package com.package.v1;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import com.package.common.dto.ResponseDTO;

@Remote
@Path("/v1/test")
public interface TestRESTServiceBA {

    @GET
    @Path("/headers")
    @Produces("application/json")
    ResponseDTO<Map<String, String>> getAllHeaders();
}
```

Version 1 Implementation

```
package com.package.v1;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.package.common.dto.ResponseDTO;
import com.package.v1.TestRESTServiceBA;

@Stateless
public class TestRESTServiceBABean implements TestRESTServiceBA {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(TestRESTServiceBABean.class);

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public TestRESTServiceBABean() {
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseDTO<Map<String, String>> getAllHeaders() {
        LOG.info("GET:v1/test/headers requested!");
        final ResponseDTO<Map<String, String>> response = new ResponseDTO<>();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Version 2 interface
    package com.package.v2;

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import com.package.common.dto.ResponseDTO;

@Remote
@Path("/v2/test")
public interface TestRESTServiceBA2 {

    @GET
    @Path("/headers")
    @Produces("application/json")
    ResponseDTO<Map<String, String>> getAllHeaders();
}
```

Version 2 Implementation
    package com.package.v2;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.package.common.dto.ResponseDTO;
import com.package.common.model.DealerSpeedUser;
import com.package.v2.TestRESTServiceBA2;


@Stateless
public class TestRESTServiceBABean implements TestRESTServiceBA {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(TestRESTServiceBABean2.class);

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public TestRESTServiceBABean2() {
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseDTO<Map<String, String>> getAllHeaders() {
        LOG.info("GET:v2/test/headers requested!");

        final ResponseDTO<Map<String, String>> response = new ResponseDTO<>();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide code? It's clearly insufficient to help you

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you it can't create an instance of an interface because you've put the `@Path` `@GET`, `@Produces`, etc. annotations on the interface classes.  Move those annotations to the TestRESTServiceBABean classes instead.